# Google API - credit endpoint

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geocoding

Google Maps Platform - geocoding API.
The assumption is not to exceed 200$ credit which is free to use.

Is there any endpoint on API for check credit?

Comment: Help or give advice about what? Do you have any trouble with using the API? If yes please add it to your question, otherwise, your question is too broad to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent exceeding the monthly $200 free credit is to set [daily quota limits](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage). Refer to [this FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_cap).

> Use a simple equation to determine your daily cap depending on how
>   much you want to spend. For example: (Monthly spend / price per
>   each)/30 = requests per day cap (for one API). For instance, on the
>   Maps JavaScript API, 28,000 calls can be made per month within the
>   free tier. If you cap your Maps JavaScript API daily quota to 903 (ie
>   28,000 / 31), you will not be charged. Note that your implementation
>   may use multiple billable APIs, so adjust your equation as needed.

Note that the Geocoding API has a free tier for up to 40,000 calls per month according to [Google's pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/). Provided this is the only Maps API you use, then you may want to cap your Geocoding API usage to about 1,290 requests per day to avoid charges.

Additionally, you can set [budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) to control your spend and you can [monitor your API usage](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-monitor) in the Cloud console.

Hope this helps.